# How do I get portions of a json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've used `jquery.get()` to retrieve and store an object, kind like this:

```
var cData = 
{
     "someitems":[
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          .....
     ]
}
```

I need to keep my structure but only get data in sets. Meaning, get records 0-3 or 4-10, something like that. I've tried using `slice()` like this:

```
var newSet = cData.someitems.slice(0,4);
```

That technically works but I lose the structure of the json.

--- EDIT ---
Per @meagar request:

I need to maintain the structure of

```
{
     "someitems":[
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          .....
     ]
}
```

Comment: `cData.someitems = cData.someitems.slice(0, 4);` You probably want to create a copy of that object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem is that there isn't a standard way of deep cloning an object in javascript, which is something you would be better off doing, if you hope to repeat your operations for multiple ranges — whilst still keeping the JSON structure surrounding those modifications.

The following is obviously designed to take into account the fact that the actual JSON data is probably more complex than what is used in the example.

```js
var cData = {
     "someitems": [
          {"id": 'a'},
          {"id": 'b'},
          {"id": 'c'},
          {"id": 'd'},
          {"id": 'e'}
     ]
};

/// there are better ways to clone objects, but as this is
/// definitely JSON, this is simple. You could of course update
/// this function to clone in a more optimal way, especially as
/// you will better understand the object you are trying to clone.
var clone = function(data){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
};

/// you could modify this method however you like, the key
/// part is that you make a copy and then modify with ranges
/// from the original
var process = function( data, itemRange ){
    var copy = clone(data);
    if ( itemRange ) {
        copy["someitems"] = data["someitems"].slice(
            itemRange[0],
            itemRange[1]
        );
    }
    return copy;
};

/// output your modified data
console.log(process(cData, [0,3]));
```

The code above should output an object with the following structure:

```
{
     "someitems": [
          {"id": 'a'},
          {"id": 'b'},
          {"id": 'c'}
     ]
}
```

... and if you change `process(cData, [0,3])` for `process(cData, [3,5])` you will get:

```
{
     "someitems": [
          {"id": 'd'},
          {"id": 'e'}
     ]
}
```

> **NOTE:** bear in mind that after the slice operation the new **`someitems`** array is re-indexed, so you will find `{id: 'd'}` at offset `0`, and not `3`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method which allows you to modify the array in-place:

```
var cData = 
{
     "someitems":[
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          {
               ...
          },
          .....
     ]
}

cData.someitems.splice(0, 4); // This will remove the first 4 elements of the array
```

Comment: Right. This leaves me with an array. I need to maintain the json format like this: `{ "someitems":[...] }`

Comment: Sure, the `cData` instance is maintained its  structure after the call to the `splice` method as shown in my answer. Only the `someitems` array is stripped from the first 4 elements which looks like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: lets say I have `{  "someitmes":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]  }` and I want the first three resulting in `{  "someitmes":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]  }`

Comment: If you want the first tree elements then simply adapt the arguments you are passing to the splice method: `cData.someitems.splice(3);`. By the way did you read the documentation of the splice method I have linked to in my answer? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice If you haven't I invite you to do so. The arguments of this method are explained pretty well along with their purpose and exact meaning.

Comment: I have to pass the json to a function and the structure `"someitems":...` is required

Comment: Alright, and that's exactly what the splice method does - it will modify the `cData.sometimes` array in-place. After that you can pass the same `cData` instance to whatever you needed to. The only difference will be in the `someitems` array property where you would have removed the required elements. When you call `cData.someitems.splice(...)` you are not modifying the `cData` structure. You are only modifying the number of elements contained in the `someitems` array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68045/discussion-between-dcp3450-and-darin-dimitrov).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first 3 items you could use this:

```
newnode = {"someitems" : cData.someitems.slice(0,3)}
```